# Schengen Visa: if the main destination consulate can't process the application in time, can you apply to other countries?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, visa-shopping

I know that for visiting multiple Schengen countries, I'm supposed to apply to the country I'm spending more time in or the country of first entrance if I'd spend equal time in the countries. However, if it seems that my local consulate of the main destination country would not be able to process the visa application in time, can I apply to other countries I'd be visiting on this trip?

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/96308/schengen-visa-appointments-not-available-for-3-months-what-are-my-options and https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71624/what-are-the-options-when-a-schengen-visa-application-is-in-processing-after-the

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> However, if it seems that my local consulate of the main destination country would not be able to process the visa application in time, can I apply to other countries I'd be visiting on this trip?

No, this plays no role in determining which Schengen country should examine your application (“competent Member State”) and the language in the [Schengen Visa Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A02009R0810-20200202) does not leave any room for exceptions.

On the other hand, it may be possible to apply to *another consulate* from the same country, see article 6(2). We have had several questions about that in the past.

Comment: Note the multiple meaning of "competent" here

Answer (score 6):

> can I apply to other countries I'd be visiting on this trip?

**Unless** you have a very good reason of why your application should be processed there, your application will be inadmissible, and you would be sent to apply at your main destination consulate.

Be warned that the authorities don't like *visa shopping* (action of choosing a specific country for some reason (ease of grant...)) very much, and I would strongly advise not getting into that

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would be a good reason? I wouldn't even be considering this if I don't have to, but my main destination consulate has a long waitlist and is not very responsive, so I'd like to know if applying to the secondary destination can be a last resort.

Comment: This answer appears to be based on pure speculation.

Comment: @EEQ A good reason would be if you change your travel plans so that you’re spending the most time in a different Schengen country from the one you’ve applied to. But you have to actually change your plans, not just pretend to.